# Tool to edit an SSIS Config that has been stored in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, config

There is an option to save SSIS configurations in SQL Server.  It seems like a nice idea.  That way my SSIS package does not need any file access to run.

But the format it is stored in is not user friendly.  Is there a tool out there that lets you view and edit these settings in a friendly manner?

Comment: How are you accessing these now? Through Management Studio or with a query? Does Jason have any advice about this in his "31 days of SSIS" series? http://www.jasonstrate.com/2011/01/31-days-of-ssis-sql-server-configuration-1831/

Comment: I made a set of SSIS packages and a c# windows form that would let you move a set of rows for a certain filter from one server to another.  I wouldn't share it, so just an idea for you.

Answer (score 0):

For viewing, we've always just used `SELECT *`

I did create a proc that exports a particular filter for our configuration table (we call it sysdtsconfig) and you can also see we've extended it with our own meta information.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
    [dbo].[ConfigurationExport]
(
    @TargetFilter VARCHAR (60)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE
        @DynamicStatement varchar(max)
    ,   @ConfigurationFilter nvarchar(150)
    ,   @ConfiguredValue nvarchar(255)
    ,   @PackagePath nvarchar(255)
    ,   @ConfiguredValueType nvarchar(20)
    ,   @Application nvarchar(50)
    ,   @Category nvarchar(50)
    ,   @Subcategory nvarchar(50)
    ,   @Comment nvarchar(255)

    -- set using statement
    SELECT
        @DynamicStatement = ''

    -- purge existing
    SELECT
        @DynamicStatement = @DynamicStatement + replicate('-', 80) + char(13) + char(10)
        + '-- Remove existing settings' + char(13) + char(10)
        + replicate('-', 80) + char(13) + char(10)

    SELECT
        @DynamicStatement = @DynamicStatement + 'DELETE C' + char(13) + char(10) +
    'FROM' + char(13) + char(10)
        + '    dbo.SYSDTSCONFIG C' + char(13) + char(10) + 'WHERE' + char(13) + char(10)
        + '    C ConfigurationFilter = ''' + @TargetFilter + '''' + char(13) + char(10)
    + char(13) + char(10)

    -- add current settings
    SELECT
        @DynamicStatement = @DynamicStatement + replicate('-', 80) + char(13) + char(10)
        + '-- Load values for ' + @TargetFilter + char(13) + char(10)
        + replicate('-', 80) + char(13) + char(10) + char(13) + char(10)

    DECLARE Csr cursor for
    SELECT
        ConfigurationFilter
    ,   ConfiguredValue
    ,   PackagePath
    ,   ConfiguredValueType
    ,   Application
    ,   Category
    ,   Subcategory
    ,   Comment
    FROM
        dbo.sysdtsconfig
    WHERE
        ConfigurationFilter = @TargetFilter


    SET NOCOUNT ON
    OPEN Csr
    FETCH NEXT FROM Csr INTO
        @ConfigurationFilter
    ,   @ConfiguredValue
    ,   @PackagePath
    ,   @ConfiguredValueType
    ,   @Application
    ,   @Category
    ,   @Subcategory
    ,   @Comment
    WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
    BEGIN
        IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
        BEGIN
        SELECT
            @DynamicStatement = @DynamicStatement + 'INSERT INTO' + char(13) + char(10)
            + '    dbo.SYSDTSCONFIG' + char(13) + char(10)
            + '(' + char(13) + char(10)
            + '    ConfigurationFilter' + char(13) + char(10)
            + ',   ConfiguredValue' + char(13) + char(10)
            + ',   PackagePath' + char(13) + char(10)
            + ',   ConfiguredValueType' + char(13) + char(10)
            + ',   Application' + char(13) + char(10)
            + ',   Category' + char(13) + char(10)
            + ',   Subcategory' + char(13) + char(10)
            + ',   Comment' + char(13) + char(10)
            + ')' + char(13) + char(10)
            + 'SELECT' + char(13) + char(10)
            + '    ' + IsNull('''' + @ConfigurationFilter + '''', 'NULL')
            + ' AS ConfigurationFilter' + char(13) + char(10)
            + ',   ' + IsNull('''' + @ConfiguredValue + '''', 'NULL') + ' AS ConfiguredValue' + char(13) + char(10)
            + ',   ' + IsNull('''' + @PackagePath + '''', 'NULL') + ' AS PackagePath' + char(13) + char(10)
            + ',   ' + IsNull('''' + @ConfiguredValueType + '''', 'NULL') + ' AS ConfiguredValueType' + char(13) + char(10)
            + ',   ' + IsNull('''' + @Application + '''', 'NULL') + ' AS Application' + char(13) + char(10)
            + ',   ' + IsNull('''' + @Category + '''', 'NULL') + ' AS Category' + char(13) + char(10)
            + ',   ' + IsNull('''' + @Subcategory + '''', 'NULL') + ' AS Subcategory' + char(13) + char(10)
            + ',   ' + IsNull('''' + @Comment + '''', 'NULL') + ' AS Comment' + char(13) + char(10) + char(13) + char(10)

        END
        FETCH NEXT FROM Csr INTO
            @ConfigurationFilter
        ,   @ConfiguredValue
        ,   @PackagePath
        ,   @ConfiguredValueType
        ,   @Application
        ,   @Category
        ,   @Subcategory
        ,   @Comment
    END
    CLOSE Csr
    DEALLOCATE Csr

    IF (len(@dynamicStatement) > 256)
    BEGIN
        SELECT rtrim('-- Warning, text may be truncated!' + char(13) + char(10)
         + '-- Tools, Options, Query Results, SQL Server, Results to Text -> ' + char(13) + char(10)
         + '--     Set Maximum number of characters to 8192') 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            rtrim(@DynamicStatement)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            @DynamicStatement
    END
END
```

If that doesn't suit you, just grab Mladen's [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) (free) and use that to script out your config table.